# Why is this property showing up undefined in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I can't seem to figure out why the first console.log is displaying the parameter correctly but the second shows undefined.

Console Log Output:

```
text
undefined
```

Code:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.getPuzzle();
}
    getPuzzle() {
    this.restProviderService.getPuzzle(this.gameService.getGameId()).subscribe(puzzle => {
      this.puzzleType = puzzle.type;
      this.puzzleValue = puzzle.value;

      console.log(this.puzzleType);

      setTimeout(this.handlePuzzle , 3000);
    });
  }
    
      handlePuzzle() {
          console.log(this.puzzleType);
          if (this.puzzleType == 'text') {
            new Vara("#text", "assets/fonts/vara/Satisfy/SatisfySL.json", [{
              text: 'hello',
              delay: 2000,
              x: 2
            }], {
              fontSize: 25,
              strokeWidth: 1.5,
              duration: 5000,
              color: "black"
            });
          }
        
    
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the function `this.handlePuzzle` to `setTimeout` the `this` representing your class is lost, and `handlePuzzle` receives the `setTimeout`'s `this` instead.

Use an arrow function instead of passing the function itself:

```js
setTimeout(() => this.handlePuzzle(), 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside JS event listeners `this` refers to the event target.
But inside the `handlePuzzle` method (sort of an event listener), you need `this` to refer to the current object instance (as usual in a method).

You have 2 solutions:

- Use an arrow callback. Arrow callbacks preserve the value of `this`.

  `setTimeout(()=>this.handlePuzzle(), 3000)`

  or in your method declaration

  `handlePuzzle=()=> { console.log(this.puzzleType);`
- Use `bind` to set the value of `this`.

  `setTimeout(this.handlePuzzle.bind(this), 3000);`

  or, in the constructor

  `this.handlePuzzle = this.handlePuzzle.bind(this);`

For more details, refer to the following article.
https://dev.to/alexdevero/a-quick-guide-to-this-keyword-in-javascript-what-this-is-and-when-7i5